# How to do refactoring for Python?

Tags: python, refactoring

Which tool people normally use when they do the refactoring for Python!?
For me, to get rid of a variable, I need to trace through the program to make sure that I completely delete it!?

Comment: This is a functionality of your IDE and depends on what you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PyCharm by JetBrain](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) supports python refactoring; netbeans python module used to have refactoring too, but it's no longer working. Other IDEs might have it too.

Please be very well aware, though, that python refactoring is not as safe as, say, java refactoring, because of the very dynamic nature of the python language.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse+pydev has a refactoring tool. But a simple ctrl+F should suffice to know where you have used the variable